# Rust self-referencing struct with a hashmap and vec indexes

Tags: rust, self-reference

I need to build an index, where first I check if a string already exists in the `store` vector, or if not, add it to the `store` and get its position in it.

Once done, I will need to consume the store, and discard the index.  I would like to avoid creating each string twice (once for the index and once for the store).

```rust
struct StringIndex {
    store: Vec<String>,
    index: HashMap<&'this str, usize>,
}

impl StringIndex {
  pub fn get_or_insert(&mut self, key: &str) -> usize {
    match self.index.entry(key) {
      Occupied(v) => v.key(),
      Vacant(v) => {
        let idx = self.store.len();
        self.store.push(key.to_string());  // Create a new clone
        v.insert(idx);
        idx
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I looked at self_cell and ouroboros, but neither seem to be targetting this use case... or  not?

Comment: You can probably do it with an `Rc<str>` instead of a `String` and `&str`.

Comment: Your use case seems very similar to this: https://matklad.github.io/2020/03/22/fast-simple-rust-interner.html

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32300133

Comment: Seems like the user who gave an answer got upset that their answer was mega-slow (150 times slower in my benchmarks), deleted their answer and -1ed the question...  Or maybe its just a coincidence that the answer was deleted AND the question got -1 at the same time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a dup-indexer [crate](https://crates.io/crates/dup-indexer) / [github](https://github.com/nyurik/dup-indexer) / [docs](https://docs.rs/dup-indexer/latest/dup_indexer/). Works with any values (both allocated and copy-able), and mega-performant:

```rust
use dup_indexer::DupIndexer;

fn main() {
    let mut di = DupIndexer::new();
    assert_eq!(0, di.insert("hello".to_string()));
    assert_eq!(1, di.insert("world".to_string()));
    assert_eq!(0, di.insert("hello".to_string()));
    assert_eq!(di.into_vec(), vec!["hello".to_string(), "world".to_string()]);
}
```

DupIndexer creates a shallow non-droppable copy of the value, and stores it in the hashmap, whereas the original value goes into the vector:

```rust
pub struct DupIndexer<T> {
    values: Vec<T>,
    lookup: HashMap<ManuallyDrop<T>, usize>,
}

// impl
pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> usize {
    let dup_value = ManuallyDrop::new(unsafe { ptr::read(&value) });
    match self.lookup.entry(dup_value) {
        Occupied(entry) => *entry.get(),
        Vacant(entry) => {
            let index = self.values.len();
            entry.insert(index);
            self.values.push(value);
            index
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the above code is safe because the hashmap only keeps the ptr:read-created copy of the original value while we own it, and the value is never modified.

Note that Miri **does** complain about this code, but only in one case: if I use `Box<T>` as the value.  I do not know if this is a valid concern or not. See the safety section with the [error output](https://github.com/nyurik/dup-indexer#safety)